# How to clear Eclipse internal web browser history or browser preference?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, metadata, browser-history

I am using Eclipse Helios (Service Release 2). I want to clear Eclipse internal web browser history.

I try following path

```
metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.browser.prefs
```

but it's not working.

Comment: I think this link might be helpful to you.
[Trimming the history list in Eclipse's internal web browser](http://nuin.blogspot.in/2008/04/trimming-history-list-in-eclipses.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the path where eclipse store URL prefrence, so go there and clean this file and restart you eclipse.

```
WORKSPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.browser.prefs
```

**note:- in this path "WORKSPACE" is your current workspace**

For more info [click here](http://nuin.blogspot.in/2008/04/trimming-history-list-in-eclipses.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is using some browser wrapper to get access to the system browser features. Try to clear your Internet Explorer history on the Windows system instead.

Comment: i tried it and its not working, they maintain separate history.

Comment: how do you know eclipse is wrapping itself around a browser ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Eclipse is wrapping not itself but a browser component, implementing own browser that comply to the current web standards is impossible for Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

I am copy pasting the content from [the link in the selected answer](http://nuin.blogspot.in/2008/04/trimming-history-list-in-eclipses.html) so that it remains even if that obscure blog goes away.

> **Trimming the history list in Eclipse's internal web browser**
>
> I use the internal web browser quite a bit when I'm developing - if
>   nothing else, it's a handy place to test out the GET requests for
>   RESTful web services. I also use Eclipse for HTML writing, and again
>   the internal browser is a useful first test of "does this look right
>   yet?". This means I build up quite a long history list, and the most
>   recent entries – the ones I'm mostly likely to be looking for –
>   require scrolling to find and re-use them. I have not, to date, found
>   a setting inside Eclipse (I'm using 3.3.2 at the time of writing this)
>   to edit the internal browser history. I'd be delighted to be proved
>   wrong.
>
> In the meantime, the workaround is to close Eclipse, then edit the
>   file
>   `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.browser.prefs`
>   where `$WORKSPACE` is your Eclipse workspace root directory. This is a
>   plain text file: my preferred text editor on Linux and Windows is
>   SciTE but it doesn't actually matter which one. This file has a
>   preference key internalWebBrowserHistory, with the format:
>
> `internalWebBrowserHistory=url|*|url|*| ...`
>
> Removing stale entries is straightforward; modifying or adding new
>   entries is perfectly doable, noting that colon characters (:) are
>   escaped with a preceding backslash (\:). Save changes, restart
>   Eclipse, done. Hopefully there will be an internal preference editor
>   to make this easier inside Eclipse in future (or, someone will point
>   out to me that I've been unobservant and that it's already there).
>
> [Written by](http://nuin.blogspot.in/2008/04/trimming-history-list-in-eclipses.html) [Ian](http://www.blogger.com/profile/04691119751088749284), 4/25/2008 10:47:00 am